# Finding combinations of rows that combined do not exceed a value in mySQL

Tags: mysql

This question requires some explanation.

- Assume I have a table with items.
- Each item has multiple characterics, called id, score, value and size (all integers).
- Some of the items are grouped into unknown groups of 3
- Each item can only be in 0 or 1 group
- Each group (another table) lists the amount of items (3) and the combined score, size and value of the 3 items

Example table for the items

Tables:

```
items(id,size,score,value)
group(grpid,tsize,tscore,tvalue)
```

example content

```
items(1,2000,3000,4000)
    ,(2,4000,5000,8000)
    ,(3,8000,3000,1000)
    ,(4,12000,1000,400)

groups(1,14000,11000,13000) -> matches item 1,2,3 combined
```

Imagine the items table has hundreds to a 1000 records and typically 10 groups of 3 items

Followup question: What about 4, 5 or even 10 sized groups.

What would be the most efficient way to find the POSSIBLE groups (in theory the search could find more then one combination of 3 items that would match a groups totals)?

Comment: I suspect that the most efficient way would be to use something other than an RDBMS :-(

Comment: yes possibly, i can however find 2-item combinations with sql easily. So before i have to resort to coding, i try to make mysql do some work for the smaller groups :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the unlucky ones: You encountered the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete and thus not solvable in polynomial time in general. You (more or less) restricted your problem to groups of size `k=3`, which eases it a little bit. Nevertheless you have `k * number_of_items` possibilities, which is quite a lot. Since you did not specify further information, I assume one must try all possible combinations.

Actually I do not see an easy solution how you can solve the problem. Sure you can just try and join the table three times.

This returns you possible groups:

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id, c.id AS c_id,
  (a.score + b.score + c.score) AS score_sum,
  (a.value + b.value + c.value) AS value_sum,
  (a.size + b.size + c.size) AS size_sum
FROM items a
INNER JOIN items b ON b.id < a.id
INNER JOIN items c ON c.id < b.id
```

One can sort out those triples which represent equivalent solutions, but just permute between a, b and c. This can be achieved by constraining the ids to be lower than the current one.

Then you must compare this with available groups:

```
SELECT a_id, b_id, c_id, groups.id
FROM
  (SELECT a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id, c.id AS c_id,
    (a.score + b.score + c.score) AS score_sum,
    (a.value + b.value + c.value) AS value_sum,
    (a.size + b.size + c.size) AS size_sum
  FROM items a
  INNER JOIN items b ON b.id < a.id
  INNER JOIN items c ON c.id < b.id
) a
INNER JOIN groups ON a.score_sum = groups.score
  AND a.value_sum = groups.value
  AND a.size_sum = groups.size
```

Though I would not expect this to run fast. Speeding this up is only possible with exploiting your particular problem.

You might re-think if there is additional information which can help solve your particular problem, or try to modify your base data.

Comment: Yes, sucha soluiton is the one i found, but its slow indeed, and i was trying to see if othe rpeople with more knowledge would come up with faster solutions. One thing i have been thinking about is to make a list (resultset) where i join twice , excluding the results that are added up already > then the group size/score/value. That would limit the amount of possibilities for the combination with the third. I have also been thinking about sorting efficiently in some way to chop off stuff. But that sounds dangerously close to using something like php, not mysql :P

Comment: I do not think you will find a faster solution. You might tune this solution a bit with indexes or like I said by changing your base data or by using further assumptions to restrict the number of rows you have to analyze. But basically this is the best one can do.

Comment: I do not see how you could exclude some joins to the third table. You must compute all pairs before you can check in which group it fits?! If you would search for one single group, then you had limits and you might be able to throw those rows away which already surpass this limits after two joins, but if you want to search in general for all groups... I do not see how you could throw pairs out before they become triples.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might look like this...

```
SELECT x.size+y.size+z.size size
     , x.score+y.score+z.score score
     , x.value+y.value+z.value value 
  FROM items x 
  JOIN items y 
    ON y.id < x.id 
  JOIN items z 
    ON z.id < y.id 
HAVING size = 14 
   AND score = 11 
   AND value = 13;
```

This solution needs as many JOINs as there are group members...however, I don't think scales so well.

Comment: Yes, that is what i came up with at first (but i made the query also do it in one go for all 3-item groups by joining with the group table). It;s just so slow so i was windering if there was more efficient way.